# Filtering the Data storage table using PartitionKey and Date time

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I want to get the data over a time period using both PartitionKey and datetime filter.

[https://sa.table.core.windows.net/ABC()?$filter=Timestamp%20gt%20datetime'2023-04-03T13:47:52.083669Z'andPartitionKey%20eq%20'123455432'](https://sa.table.core.windows.net/ABC()?$filter=Timestamp%20gt%20datetime%272023-04-03T13:47:52.083669Z%27andPartitionKey%20eq%20%27123455432%27)

I have tried this query to get the partitionkeys which are generated after the datetime given but when i am trying , I am getting a 400 (Bad request) error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason you are getting this error is because you did not include spaces at proper places.

Please try the following:

[https://sa.table.core.windows.net/ABC()?$filter=Timestamp%20gt%20datetime'2023-04-03T13:47:52.083669Z'%20and%20PartitionKey%20eq%20'123455432'](https://sa.table.core.windows.net/ABC()?$filter=Timestamp%20gt%20datetime%272023-04-03T13:47:52.083669Z%27%20and%20PartitionKey%20eq%20%27123455432%27)

Notice how I added a space before and after `and`.